# jQuery :has() equivalent using document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery

As I wrote in the topic - I am looking for a jQuery :has() selector equivalent using document.querySelector.

For example I would like to select all paragraphs that contains links:

With jQuery it will be simple:

```
$("p:has(a)")
```

How to achieve that using javascript's document.querySelector?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is one as :has() is a special selector from jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

> Because :has() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :has() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method

There is no native equivalent.

Comment: Note that contrary to that statement [`:has()` is a part of the CSS Selectors Level 4 specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/selectors/#relational).

Answer (score 6):

A `:has('selector')` equivalent in vanilla JS would be basically what goes on in the jQuery extension: match the selector, then filter out elements that don't return a match for the child selector:

```
[].filter.call( document.querySelectorAll('p'), function( elem ){
   return elem.querySelector('a')
});
```

Or a more general function:

```
var querySelectorHas = function( parent, child ){
   return [].filter.call( document.querySelectorAll( parent ), function( elem ){
       return elem.querySelector( child )
   });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jer5xde5/

Answer (score 3):

In [Chrome 105+](https://caniuse.com/css-has) you can use the `:has` pseudo selector:

```js
document.querySelector(`a:has(b)`).classList.add('mark')
```

```css
.mark {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a>1</a>
<a><b>2</b></a>
<a>3</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

There is no equivalent of `:has()` in Javascript. If you want to do so you can do manually [**childNode**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes).

With childNode you need to iterate it manually using loop.